# Pygame: Click event is affecting every sprite to the left of them

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I have an array with all the sprites inside of them, and in the loop, if the sprite is clicked then the sprite is killed.

If I click the sprites from left to right, everything is fine. They are cleared one by one independent of each other. But, if I click the sprite most right of the screen, it kills everything to the left of it.

Full code because I've no idea where the important region might be.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import random
pygame.init()
level = 1
cooldown = 1000
class test(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, w):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([600,600])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("index.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (w,w))
        self.last = pygame.time.get_ticks()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([600,600])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background.fill([0,0,0])
rX = random.randint(0, 500)
rX2 = random.randint(0, 500) 
screen.blit(background, (0,0))
sp = []
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
a_1 = test(random.randint(40,60))
a_1.rect.x = rX
a_1.rect.y = -400
sp.append(a_1)
all_sprites_list.add(a_1)

#The steps for a_1 is repeated to make variables a_2, a_3, a_4...  

Running = True
while Running:
    now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    for x in sp:
        x.rect.y+=level
    m_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            Running = False
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            for s in sp:
                if s.rect.collidepoint(m_pos):
                    s.kill()
    pygame.display.flip()
    all_sprites_list.clear(screen, background)
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    all_sprites_list.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: use `print()` in place where you kill elements to see values in variables.

Comment: I tried code and it works correctly for me.

Comment: Don't put your sprites into a separate list, because when you call `sprite.kill()` the sprite gets only removed from the sprite groups but not from the list. So if you need a separate list of sprites, use another `pygame.sprite.Group` instead of a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is because in class you create `Surface` with size `(600, 600)` and you assign this size to `self.rect`. After that you load image but you forgot to assign its size to `self.rect` so program always check mouse click with size `(600, 600)` and when you click most right item then all rect `(600, 600)` are in area of click.

But you don't have to create `Surface` if you load image.

---

**My version with many changes.**

I removed list `sp` because I can use `all_sprites_list`

When it sends `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event then mouse position is in `event.pos` so I don't need `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`

```
import pygame
import random

# --- classes --- (UpperCaseNames)

class Test(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, w):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load("index.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (w, w))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.last = pygame.time.get_ticks()

# --- main ----

level = 1
cooldown = 1000

# - init -

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

# - items -

background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background.fill((0, 0, 0))

screen.blit(background, (0,0))

all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

for x in range(10):
    item = Test(random.randint(40, 60))
    item.rect.x = 40 * random.randint(0, 10)
    item.rect.y = 0
    all_sprites_list.add(item)

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True

while running:

    now = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    for item in all_sprites_list:
        item.rect.y += level

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            for item in all_sprites_list:
                if item.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    item.kill()

    pygame.display.flip()
    all_sprites_list.clear(screen, background)
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    all_sprites_list.update()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```